# dompdf images (in codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I'm creating a pdf that has 3 images.

- 2 images are from my own server
- 1 is from an external server
- DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to true
- all images are called via `<img src="http://domain.com/image.jpg" />`

now the problem is that of the 3 images only 1 works, the external server one.
Having tested a whole lot of combinations, it will pull any images from any other server but my own. I dono what's going on.

Why is it only my own server that is causing the problem?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, the images from your own server are also called using http://example.com/image.jpg? If you open the HTML page in your web browser do all the images resolve ok?

Comment: yeah all external connections to the server were working. Just the iptables were stuffed up so that it couldn't access itself. Switched to UFW on ubuntu 10.04 LTS. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. It as the server and the firewall that prevented requested from itself.

e.g. wget http://myserver.com/image.jpg wasn't working